# How to set different wording for different English locales

Tags: apex

I understand with custom labels and translation workbench we can show text differently in different language background. It only has the options of different languages. Say I am here in Australia and we are also supporting US. So we have two language sets en-us and en-au. And they are slightly different with each other in text wording.

So what is the common way in achieving this usually. Should I create a custom class myself and query the locale or custom setting for it?

Comment: This seems like it has been asked on SFSE before. I'll see if I can find.